# Convert List or Collection to VisualBasicValue

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I was wondering if there is a way to convert a

```
List<T>
```

to a

```
VisualBasicValue<List<T>>
```

programmatically with reflection or something ?

At least with T is string or ValueType.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Christophe, try to use VisualBasicReference class , for more information read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780235(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: Hi Lior. I tried to. I can't initialize the VisualBasicReference from a List. How would you do that ?